# Multiple calls in batch file emit stack limit exceed error

Tags: batch-file

This batch file:

```
@echo off

echo ################# Run tests. #####################

CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"
CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"
CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"
CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"
CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"

echo ################# End of tests #####################
GOTO:EOF

:Run
GOTO:EOF
```

shows the error:

```
C:> run_all_tests.bat
################# Run tests. #####################
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=339, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

However, if I shrink the number of calls like this:

```
@echo off

echo ################# Run tests. #####################

CALL :Run "1_test"
CALL :Run "2_test"
CALL :Run "3_test"
CALL :Run "4_test"
CALL :Run "5_test"
CALL :Run "6_test"
CALL :Run "7_test"
CALL :Run "8_test"
CALL :Run "9_test"
CALL :Run "10_test"

echo ################# End of tests #####################
GOTO:EOF

:Run
GOTO:EOF
```

it outputs no error.

```
C:> run_all_tests.bat
################# Run tests. #####################
################# End of tests #####################
```

Is it legitimate to call the same label multiple times?
AFAIK, there is no doc about the limitation in the number of calls in a batch file.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but I have no idea. Any help?

Comment: Are you going to show us what the code is under `:Run`? or are you sure that it is absolutely irrelevant to the question?

Comment: When you `call` a subroutine you don't need to `goto:eof`!

Comment: can't replicate (your script runs fine for me)

Comment: @double-beep: but it doesn't hurt

Comment: Of course not! @Stephan he didn't provide the whole code. We can no longer reproduce his problem. Going to flag this.

Comment: only way to get this error is to recursively call a routine (e.g. inside `:run` another `call :run`). So yes, you don't show us all relevant code.

Comment: @Compo Yes, there is no codes under `:Run`. I surprised that this is not reproducible on yours. Let me try on another PC.

Comment: @double-beep This is the whole code. But I noticed that this is not reproducible on my another PC, which is the same version of Windows. I'm confused.

Comment: @Stephan No, this is the whole codes. But I think this seems not a code problem, rather an environment problem on my problematic machine.

Answer (score 3):

`CALL` recursion can exceed the stack limits when you issue too many `CALL`s before others have returned from their respective `CALL`.

A batch file returns from a `CALL` whenever it reaches either:

1. the end of the script
2. `EXIT /B`
3. `GOTO :EOF`

As the code you've provided has a definite `GOTO:EOF` under the `:Run` label, it is clear that whatever command or commands you've omitted from the code you've provided is still running, i.e. has not reached the `GOTO:EOF` before subsequent `CALL`s are made.

In order to fix the problem you're going to have to restructure the code in such a way as to prevent multiple `CALL`s being issued prior to previous ones being returned. This will entail, at the outset, fixing the code you've not shown us.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is no other codes under `:Run`. However, it seems that this is not reproducible on your machine, let me check on my another PC. I'll be back with result.

Comment: I can't reproduce on my another PC. Their cmd.exe are showing the same version, `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.472]` when launched. I'm confused, what can be wrong?

Comment: I think I found a reason. My original batch file's line ending is UNIX style, so LF only. If it is changed to Windows style, i.e., CR and LF, the problem is gone. The reason why the problem is not shown on my another PC is that I made a batch file via copy & paste, which ends up with Windows style line endings. Anyway, I'm still curious why line ending causes the problem.